# Upload file FTP with Filesystem Laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to upload an excel file to my ftp but i get

> ftp_fput(): Could not open file for writing.

My file is stored at : storage/app

The connection to the ftp is working great ! i tested

$file = 'test.txt'

it's working the file is uploaded to the ftp. but when i try to store the excel file it's doesn't work. hope someone could help me with that. thanks a lot in advance

here my code :

```
$file = Excel::create('' . $date . '' , function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);

        });

    });

    $ftp = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::createFtpDriver([
        'host'     => '....',
        'username' => '....',
        'password' => '....',
        'port'     => '..',
        'timeout'  => '..',
        'root' => '/...',
    ]);

    $ftp->put($file->store("xlsx", false, true)['full'], 'upload');
```

Comment: I recommend not using ftp. Avoid if possible. It is not very secure.

Comment: what is the best to do without using ftp Jack ?

Comment: You could implement a transfer of files via HTTPS using a REST endpoint. OR you could use an S3 bucket with Amazon. The latter is nice because it makes it easier to work with files. Please refer to https://www.majentasolutions.com/blog/3-reasons-why-your-business-shouldnt-use-ftp-to-exchange-data/ OR you can just google "FTP insecure" and a bunch of articles will explain the security holes of FTP.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your FTP user has permission to upload files to the FTP server / directories.

You may first need to store the excel file locally by doing:

```
$file->store("xlsx", false, true);
```

Then calling:

```
$ftp->put( $date . '.xlsx', 'upload');
```

Then you can delete the locally created file.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i still get : ftp_fput(): Could not open file for writing. the file is correctly storing to storage/app but not uploaded to the ftp

Comment: Check your storage folder permissions. Permissions are always tricky with file stuff. Make sure you can write/read to the storage folder (recursively) and your web server can access to such folder with no problems.